# Safely add/remove ListView item from different thread

Tags: android, listview

After filling a `ListView` from local `SQLite` I want to fetch data over the network from a remote Database in order to retrieve new Data, and show it in the `ListView` so that the local `SQLite` Database is just a fallback method in case of no internet.

I was using a different `Thread` to insert the network-fetched data into the SQLite and then re-fill the `ListView` list.

Naturally, the app crashes because at some point the second `Thread` is removing every item on the list (to add new ones) and at the time, the `UI Thread` is trying to access an index who's been deleted by the secondary thread.

Since this is for academical purpose, the idea is not using external/custom libraries, so what'd be a good approach that doesn't include custom libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the database in a content provider. Not difficult to do, since you already have the database. Instead of writing your own Thread, use an IntentService to fetch the network data and write it into the content provider.

In your Activity, use a CursorLoader to load the data from the content provider in the background. CursorLoader includes an implementation of onDataSetChanged(), so every time the content provider is updated, the Cursor will be reloaded. Every time the Cursor reloads, swap the new Cursor into the CursorAdapter that backs your ListView.

To communicate between the IntentService and your Activity, do two things:

- Send a local broadcast Intent (using LocalBroadcastManager) from the IntentService to the
  Activity when the network download completes. If your Activity is in the foreground, it
  will get the broadcast immediately, and you can fire off CursorLoader for the first time.
- Also post a notification from the IntentService. In this notification, include a content
  Intent. If your Activity is in the background and the IntentService completes, the user
  sees the notification. He or she can then click the notification to go back to your
  Activity. You can fire off CursorLoader if you need to, or what until CursorLoader restarts automatically.

Your issue points out the desirability of rethinking app structure when you're programming in Android. Android apps aren't linear; they're more like mega-objects that interact with each other according to their current state. For this reason, you should avoid writing your entire app in one Activity, or writing it from the top down.

Also, there's hardly ever a reason to create a new Thread() on your own. Android offers plenty of classes that handle asynchronous processing for you. If you find yourself coding a Thread() or run(), be wary.

Answer (score 0):

Only update the `ListView` on the main application thread. For example, instead of a `Thread`, use an `AsyncTask`, where you do your disk and network I/O in `doInBackground()` and update the `ListView` in `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0):

Because the data shown in `ListView` is shared, you have to protect it via synchronization. You should write the code `synchronized (data) {// data operation}` in different thread in case of  crash